# Generate two arrays from a list of pairs

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Suppose I have the following arrays

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

And I created the list

```
c = [(1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (3,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6)]
```

How can I create two lists as follows:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=[]
b=[]
for i in c:
   a.append(i[0])
   b.append(i[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` with tuple unpacking here.

```
a, b = zip(*c)
print(a) # (1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3)
print(b) # (4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6)
```

---

Since, numpy is tagged, you can directly generate the required data using [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

a = np.repeat(a, 3)
b = np.tile(b, (3, ))
print(a) # array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
print(b) # array([4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert c to numpy array, first column is a second column is b

```py
c = np.array(c)
a = c[:, 0]
b = c[:, 1]
```